# Having trouble encrypting and decrypting with cmp

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm having an issue now with the cmp. I need incorporate 3 tables to encrypt and decrypt. I can play with the code to either do n_tab, l_tab, or a_tab but can't seem to make sense of incorporating all three. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

```
.model small

.stack 100h

.data


    prompt1 db "ENTER YOUR MESSAGE HERE: $" 
    prompt2 db "ENCRYPTED: $"
    prompt3 db "DECRYPTED: $"

    a_tab db "ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA"



    buff  db 50 dup(0)  


    .code

    main:
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax                      ; set up addressability
    mov si, offset buff             ; put into buff

    lea dx, prompt1                 ; load and print the string PROMPT
    mov ah, 9
    int 21h
    mov si, di

    mov ah, 3fH
    mov cx, 50
    int 21h
    mov si, di





    mov bx, offset a_tab
    mov si, di

    l1: lodsb
    push bx
    mov ah, 6
    mov dl, 0ffh
    int 21h
    pop bx
    mov dl, al
    mov al, 0
    sub al, 'A'

    xlat
    loop l1

    lea dx, prompt2                 ; load and print the string PROMPT
    mov ah, 9
    int 21h
    mov si, di

    mov ah, 4cH
    int 21h

end main
```

Comment: You might want to look at [this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29313454/xlat-with-3-lookup-tables) which has a couple of answers.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few problems I see which I'll describe. Sorry I don't have DOS or a DOS emulator or Windows set up to test this, so I'm just reading through your code. There may be other issues as well, but these are significant ones:

```
    mov ah, 3fH
    mov bx, 0
    mov cx, 50
    mov dx, offset buff         ; put into buff
    int 21h
```

The start of this segment sets up a file I/O to read from file handle `0` (standard input). When the `int 21h` returns, the actual number of bytes read is in `ax`, but this seems to be ignored, ultimately.

Then the loop starts...

```
l1:
    mov dl, al
    mov bx, offset a_tab
```

You're now beginning your encryption loop. You've moved the low byte of the number of bytes read from the user into `dl` and loaded the `a_tab` address into `bx` to set up for the `xlat` which expects the table address to be in `ds:bx` and will index that table by the value in `al`, loading the result into `al`.

```
    xlat
```

So here we already have trouble. What was in `al` when this `xlat` was first performed? It had the number of bytes read in from standard input, which is probably not what you intended. I assume the `mov dl, al` was somehow intended to get the next character out of the buffer, which we need to get into `al` before the `xlat` call. But that means we have to read it out of the buffer. Whither the buffer index or the advancing buffer pointer in the loop? It doesn't appear to be setup.

Moving on...

```
    mov ah, 6
    mov dl, 0ffh
    int 21h
```

This outputs the character that's in `al` to the terminal. So whatever you retrieved from `a_tab` using the number of bytes read from the terminal as an index is what you should be seeing as the first character output.

Remember the instruction at `l1:` above that did the `mov dl, al`? That seems to have no effect since `dl` hasn't been used yet and is now being overwritten with `0ffh` for the above DOS interrupt.

```
    lea dx, prompt2               ; load and print the string PROMPT
    loop l1
```

This says you're loading and printing the prompt string, which seems like that's what you're starting to do (with the `lea`) but then you do a `loop` to `l1`. I assume the `loop` instruction belongs *before* the `lea` instruction here. The `loop` will decrement the counter in `cx` and jump to `l1` if the result is not zero. However, what is in `cx`? Answer: UNCERTAIN because the last DOS interrupt we executed to output a character may have altered `cx` since it's not guaranteed to preserve registers. And even if it did the last known value of `cx` was from the `mov cx, 50` which set up the *maximum* buffer size (not the *actual* buffer size, which was returned by the buffer read but ignored by the code). That interrupt might also have obliterated `cx`.

I'm supposing you are trying to index the translation table with the input characters. You have to first decide whether you're doing upper case, lower case, or both for your input, then have enough entries in the output table, `a_tab` to account for that. You need to read in a character, subtract off the lowest possible character value (which would be `'A'` if you're using upper case letters), then use that value to index your table.

You're seeing garbled output because there's really no telling what's in `al` by the time you execute your `xlat` instruction each time through the loop.

To make the code work properly, here are some steps to follow:

**Before the loop**

1. Read the input string buffer, as you are doing is fine, and save the number of bytes actually read into the loop counter, `cx`. All of the x86 `loop` instructions use `cx` as a counter.
2. Set up a spare register, say `si` as the address of the current buffered input character (set `si` to `buf` to start). The `si` register is ideal for buffer indexing (look up the `lods`, `stos`, etc, instructions).

**During the loop**

1. Read a byte from the input buffer into `al` (you can use the `lodsb` instruction to do this which will then automatically increment `si` for the next load)
2. If you're reading all caps input, subtract `'A'` from character in `al`. If everything is lower case, then subtract `'a'`. You need to zero-base your index into `a_tab`.
3. Put the address of `a_tab` into `bx`
4. Execute your `xlat` instruction which will load the translated result into `al`.
5. Save any registers you care about onto the stack using `push`; this includes the `cx` register which is your current loop counter and the `si`
6. Use the DOS interrupt to output the character in `al`
7. Restore the registers you previously saved in step 5 using `pop`
8. Go around the loop with the `loop` instruction which will decrement the loop counter, `cx`.

These are the overall steps. You may want to do other things around this as well, but this should help get you on the right track. You should also read the documentation online for special instructions such as `xlat` and `lodsb` carefully to understand their behavior. In addition, anytime you call a DOS interrupt or function, it has conventions for how to pass arguments, and how information might be returned in registers. Any other registers not mentioned that you need *might* get used by that interrupt or function without you knowing, so you should save those registers before doing such calls, using `push` for example, and then restore them after the call using `pop`.

Comment: @Iceman you didn't really describe your algorithm other than to show the code, so I can't answer that question. What I can tell you is that `xlat` will index a table with the value that's in `al` and retrieve that value in memory and store it back into `al`. If your encryption seems to be character by character, table lookup based, then it should work. But your code has several issues outlined above that have nothing to do with whether you're using `xlat`.

Comment: @Iceman as you read each character out of the input buffer you need to convert it to a suitable index into the table, which has to start at `0` as the lowest index. If your input is all UPPER CASE letters, then you would read a character from the input buffer, subtract the value of `'A'` from it to make it zero-based, then use that in `al` when doing the `xlat` to retrieve the character you want to translate to.

Comment: @Iceman, I added some description to my answer to help solve the problem.