# xlat with 3 lookup tables

Tags: assembly, x86

I have been trying to get this code to work for a while now. I am having trouble seeing how to use 3 lookup tables. Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong and point me in the right direction. I am trying to compare so i can use the upper, lower, and number. I can't find much on multiple lookup tables. Thank you very much for any help provided.

```
 .model small

.stack 100h

.data

prompt1 db "ENTER YOUR MESSAGE HERE: $" 
prompt2 db 13,10,13,10,"ENCRYPTED/DECRYPTED MESSAGE: $"

a_tab db "ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA"
l_tab db "zyxvwutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba"
n_tab db "9876543210"


buff  db 51          ;MAXIMUM NUMBER OF CHARACTERS ALLOWED (50).
      db ?           ;NUMBER OF CHARACTERS ENTERED BY USER.
      db 51 dup('$') ;CHARACTERS ENTERED, ENDED BY CHR(13).

.code

main:
mov ax, @data
mov ds, ax                      ; set up addressability

lea dx, prompt1                 ; load and print the string PROMPT
mov ah, 9
int 21h

;CAPTURE STRING FROM KEYBOARD (WITH "BUFF" FORMAT).
lea dx, buff
mov ah, 0AH ;0AH REQUIRES THE THREE-LEVEL FORMAT OF BUFF.
int 21h

;--------------------------------------------------------------------    
;MAKE "SI" TO POINT TO FIRST CAPTURED CHARACTER.
lea si, buff
inc si ;NOW "SI" POINTS TO THE NUMBER OF CHARACTERS ENTERED BY USER.
inc si ;NOW "SI" POINTS TO FIRST ENTERED CHARACTER.



encryptmessage:
mov al, [si]        ;GET CHARACTER.
cmp al, 32          ;check if blank space
je space


cmp al, 13          ;CHECK IF END REACHED.
je  encrypted

cmp al, 'Z'-'A'
jbe uppercase

cmp al, 'z'-'a'
jbe lowercase

cmp al, '9'-'0'
jbe number

uppercase:
mov bx, offset a_tab
sub al, 'A'         ;ENCRYPT CHARACTER

lowercase:
mov bx, offset l_tab
sub al, 'a'         ;ENCRYPT CHARACTER

number:
mov bx, offset n_tab
sub al, '0'         ;ENCRYPT NUMBER

xlat 
space:
mov [si], al        ;PUT CHARACTER BACK.
inc si              ;NEXT CHARACTER.
jmp encryptmessage
encrypted:   



lea dx, prompt2
mov ah, 9
int 21h

lea dx, buff
add dx, 2
mov ah, 9
int 21h

mov ah, 4cH
int 21h

end main
```

Comment: `cmp al, 'Z' - 'A'` (etc.) is not doing what you want. Use two comparisons. Got a debugger?

Comment: no debugger. I do sort of no how to step through dos debugger but not well enough yet. When you say use 2 comparisons what do you mean? I'm using three now.

Comment: Your 'uppercase:' and 'lowercase:' labels fall through to 'number:' so bx will always be 'offset n_tab'. And the subtracted values add, too. For example, 'uppercase:' will reduce AL by 'A'+'a'+'0' most likely resulting in a "negative number".

Comment: I do see and I felt that is what was happening but is there a logical solution? I just can't see how to use three different look up tables?

Comment: What I am trying to do is, if you enter: MEET ME AT 8 encrypt will be: NVVG NVZG 1. Then if I enter: NVVG NVZG 1 it will decrypt to: MEET ME AT 8. But also the same with lower case.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to compare here is by respecting the ASCII order of the characters. First come the numbers, then come the uppercase characters and last come the lowercase characters. The holes between them need not be translated and thus they are treated as space. You no longer need to check for 32 separatedly.

```
encryptmessage:
  mov al, [si]        ;GET CHARACTER.
  cmp al, 13          ;CHECK IF END REACHED.
  je  encrypted

  cmp al, '0'
  jb  Space
  cmp al, '9'
  jbe Number
  cmp al, 'A'
  jb  Space
  cmp al, 'Z'
  jbe Uppercase
  cmp al, 'a'
  jb  Space
  cmp al, 'z'
  ja  Space
Lowercase:
  mov bx, offset l_tab
  sub al, 'a'
  jmp Translate
Uppercase:
  mov bx, offset a_tab
  sub al, 'A'
  jmp Translate
Number:
  mov bx, offset n_tab
  sub al, '0'
Translate:
  xlat 
Space:
  mov [si], al        ;PUT CHARACTER BACK.
  inc si              ;NEXT CHARACTER.
  jmp encryptmessage
encrypted:
```

At the conclusion of your program you print the encrypted message but consider what would happen if the user indeed inputted 50 characters! The terminating CR would no longer be followed by the mandatory **$** character. Might I suggest you enlarge the buffer by 1 byte.

```
buff  db 51          ;MAXIMUM NUMBER OF CHARACTERS ALLOWED (50).
      db ?           ;NUMBER OF CHARACTERS ENTERED BY USER.
      db 51 dup('$') ;CHARACTERS ENTERED, ENDED BY CHR(13).
      db '$'
```

Answer (score 0):

What I had in mind was two comparisons per table. Comparing to `'Z' - 'A'` tells us that there are 26 letters - not useful information.

```
cmp al, 'Z'
ja notupper
cmp al, 'A'
jae uppercase

notupper:
cmp al, 'z'
ja notlower
; etc.
```

When you get to `uppercase` (etc.), set `bx` to your table, and do the appropriate subtraction (as you do), but then don't "fall through" to the next case, but jump to your `do_xlat:` label. I leave it to your imagination where that should be. :)